# How to get field name from Java interface value?

Tags: java, reflection, interface, parameters

I have some cowboy code that needs a little refinement.  I'd like to improve documentational logging without the shame of a huge hard-coded switch statement.

In the following code, I'd like to be able to call a utility, pass it an interface and a value and have it return the name of the field that is initialized to that value.  So, if an interface has public static int ONE = 1, then the return value of (T,1) should be "ONE".  Like this:

```
public interface SOBConstants
{
    public static final int EVENT_WILLIE      = 0;
    public static final int EVENT_LOPEZ       = 1;
    public static final int EVENT_GETS_HIS    = 2;
    public static final int EVENT_DUE         = 3;
}

public class Mordecai implements SOBConstants
{
    public void handleEvent(int eventid )
    {
        // Existing log entry:
        log.debug("Handling event" + id );

        // New log entry:
        log.debug("Handling event " + Utils.eventName( SOBConstants, eventid );
        // Should output "Handling event EVENT_WILLIE", etc.

        switch( eventid )
        {
            case EVENT_WILLIE :
                super.attachVictim();
                break;
            case EVENT_LOPEZ :
                super.confirmVictim();
                break;
            case EVENT_GETS_HIS :
                super.openStreetFader();
                break;
            case EVENT_DUE :
                super.animateDescent();
                super.playOutro();
                break;
            default :
                super.detachAndContinueSearch();
        }
        return;
    }
}

public class Utils
{
    public static String eventName(Object container, int eventID)
    {
        String s = "";

        if( container != null )
        {
            Field[] flist = container.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field f : flist )
                if( f.getType() == int.class )
                    try {
                        if( f.getInt(null) == eventID ) {
                            s = f.getName();
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    }
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

How can I write (or call) Utils.eventName to allow any interface to be passed and scanned for the field name whose value is also passed?  I'd like to focus on the interface rather than passing the implementing class, because that would require some additional discriminator to be added.  Currently, the field list is empty either way.

Or is this OK as-is and I just need to call like

```
Utils.getName(new SOBConstants(){}, 3 );
```

**Also note: I considered using actual enums but this seems like an OK time/effort interim improvement (there are 100's of constants).**  So DON'T suggest enums.  Not relevant.

Thanks!
HS

Comment: Using an enum would be a *much* better idea. It's easier to convert a value to its string representation, *and* you get to make sure the right event type is only used for the right event handler. I'd go for that solution.

Comment: @Jon - I totally agree, except there is way too much code to touch for that within the timeframe I have to make this incremental improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Use an enumeration.

```
public enum SOBConstants
{
  EVENT_WILLIE (0),
  EVENT_LOPEZ (1),
  EVENT_GETS_HIS (2),
  EVENT_DUE (3);

  private int value;
  private SOBConstants(int value) { this.value = value; }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public MyReturnType doSomething(Object arg) {
    // do new functionality
  }
}
```

Then you can add whatever methods you want to the enumeration for any related functionality you need.

Comment: Jeez, although, well, thanks, um I have already said - now 3 times - that enum is NOT the solution.  The task is read/parse the existing interface, not rewrite it correctly.

Comment: It took me one minute to change your class into my class. It's not as long as you think, making `enum`s is very straightforward. It will take you a lot longer to write workarounds that in will be to do it correctly.

Comment: OK, well, like I said, "Thanks" but this is answering YOUR question, not MY question.  I want the answer to "how to pass and parse an interface", not how to avoid doing so by redesigning.